# Exe does not contain Version in Properties/Details

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I have a C# project and have specified assembly and file versions.
But under the Properties/Details of the Project.exe the field File version is empty. Do I have to set up something in project settings or is it a normal behavior?

Assembly.cs:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Application")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Firm")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Application")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Firm ©  2014")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("long guid")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersionAttribute("1.0.1")]
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think an assembly must be signed to contain these fields, otherwise anyone could tamper with them.

Comment: Can you send your AssemblyInfo.cs here ? do you have multiple AssemblyFileVersion attrribute in your project ?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis: No.

Comment: Try specifying "1.0.1.0" instead of just "1.0.1".

Comment: So, I have found an interesting thing: my project uses resourcefile with icons, that`s why under project settings/Application/Resources instead of "Icon and Manifest" I have chosen Resource file. If I choose "Icon and Manifest" the data with file version will be written to file properties. So my question is now, if I use a custom Resource file with icons, what do I have to do, that the file contains versions (I think I have to specify a new manifest for it). It would be great if I could use the assembly data from Project settings/Assembly info instead of specifying a new copy for it

Comment: @RenniePet: it is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have solved my problem the following way:

- I have set under Project properties/Application back to "Icon and Manifest" and specified the single icon for my project
- To embed multiple icons into my exe without Win32-Resource I have used [InsertIcons.exe](http://einaregilsson.com/add-multiple-icons-to-a-dotnet-application/)

So the problem was: if you specify a Win32-Resource for your Icons, then no manifest file will be embedded into the output exe. In this case you possibly have to add to this resource a version resource to include the version data. In this case you have to define the version, build etc. manually for every build you make (I have found no other way to avoid this behavior). Strangely the software itself will be still able to get data from own AssemblyInformation even without adding version resource.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the AssemblyInfo.cs file of your executable project and make sure that file has the attribute `[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]` set properly (where 1.0.0.0 is the version you want).